# Using STR_TO_DATE() before pushing to Database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm pushing values into a MySQL database I need to take the code I have now and integrate the `STR_TO_DATE()` function.

The `STR_TO_DATE()` function needs to be applied to both `$start` & `$end`.

```
$qstring = "INSERT INTO tbl_events VALUES(NULL,'".$name."','".$day."','".$start."','".$end."','".$location."','".$description."','".$type."')";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);
```

Date Format is "08/03/2011 09:05"

I've already tried replacing `$start` with `STR_TO_DATE($start)` it kills the php script.

Comment: Well, for starters, what format is your date in? and then what is the question after that? You just wrap your start/end in str_to_date w/ the relevant format.

Comment: so? replace `$start` with `STR_TO_DATE($start)`?

Comment: I have already tried replacing $start with STR_TO_DATE($start) it kills the php script.

Comment: Did you do `"... '".STR_TO_DATE($start)."'"` or `"STR_TO_DATE( ".$start." )"`? It's a MySQL function so the latter is correct (but add the second parameter). Also, change the second line to `$result = mysql_query($qstring) or die( mysql_error() );` to see MySQL errors.

Comment: Also also, "kills the php script" with what error message?

Comment: $qstring = "INSERT INTO tbl_events VALUES(NULL,'".$name."','".$day."','STR_TO_DATE( ".$start." )','".$end."','".$location."','".$description."','".$type."')";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lose the quotes around `STR_TO_DATE()` (it's a function, not a string) and add them around `$start` (that needs to be a string). Then add the second parameter as Mihai suggests.

```
$qstring = "INSERT INTO tbl_events 
  VALUES(NULL,'$name','$day', 
  STR_TO_DATE( '$start', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i' ), 
  STR_TO_DATE( '$end', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i' ), 
  '$location','$description','$type')";
$result = mysql_query($qstring) or die( mysql_error() );
```

Note that you don't need to do `"INSERT... '".$var."'..."`, it's more readable and less error prone if you do `"INSERT ... '$var' ..."`

Answer (score 0):

What is your `$start` and `$end` format ?

```
STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y')
STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2013','%M %d,%Y')
```

those are 2 ways  ... it all depends on your date format

Comment: Date Format is "08/03/2011 09:05"

Comment: ``$start = '08/03/2011 09:05';`` ->
``STR_TO_DATE($start,'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i')``

Comment: Like this? STR_TO_DATE('$start','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i')

Comment: ``STR_TO_DATE($start,'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i')`` yes

Comment: Ok I have edited my file with your suggested changes and end up with the following code
    `$start = STR_TO_DATE(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['start']),'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i');`
causes server problem.

Comment: It's not a PHP function. You have to add it to the MySQL query string.